# Adding stripe payment gateway to rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to add stripe payment gateway to my rails application but I'm getting an error as I get to the payment details. The error is 'Couldn't find Shoppe::Order with 'id'='

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:

```
def payment
 @order = Shoppe::Order.find(session[:current_order_id])
  if request.post?
    if @order.accept_stripe_token(params[:stripe_token])
      redirect_to checkout_confirmation_path`enter code here`
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Could not exchange Stripe token. Please try again."
    end
  end
end
```

i'm following the tutorial documentation on the shoppe website http://tryshoppe.com/docs/payment-gateways/stripe. 
The rails app is saying line 2 of the code above is the issue, I think its something to do with the 'current_order_id'. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the id outputting as? Is it nil? Perhaps the current_order_id isn't saving to the session hash?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new  to rails.  I'm not sure if it's saving to the session hash, how do I check this? maybe I could show you a different file?

Comment: Either use a debugger, output to logger (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger), or just write "puts session[:current_order_id]" and then look at what's being output in the server console when that method is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple example of Stripe payment for Ruby on Rails I've made recently. Check the code on GitHub here: https://github.com/ab00zar/StripePayment-example

Run the server using your test keys like: PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_g0XSu8r2ugAETksVJQXJjU30 SECRET_KEY=sk_test_A3rwGLOMNxEKDkaJOTgi4frd rails s

Answer (score 0):

in payment method, my solution idea:

```
#comment out first line.
#@order = Shoppe::Order.find(session[:current_order_id])

#Add line from below:
@order = Shoppe::Order.find(current_order.id)
```

works for me.